# iOS app folders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm looking for an idea in order to reproduce the look of the iOS app folders (menu on iPhone/iPad).
I'm wondering how is it possible to separate the background image in order to make appear the content of the folder.
Does someone already do this ? Or have an idea on how we can do ?

**EDIT :** I'm trying to reproduce this effect.

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/873912photo.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually looked at this a while back.

This is how i approached the problem:

You have a background view (the image) and a layer on top (the icons).

1. Calculate the split line.
2. Split the view and layer into tow along the split line
3. Add the content of the folder under the image.
4. Add you folder icon on top of everything.
5. Animate the bottom part down while changing opacity of the layer icon.( so you can see the content underneath)
6. While animating you should probably mask the triangle under the icon to it gives that bubble effect.
7. To close, just reverse the animation.

I didn't manage to make it work 100% but i can tell you it works (at least some parts of it).

And before you ask, no, i cannot give you the code because i didn't keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Try make screenshot like this:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight));
    [self.view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

You can make two screenshots and add with different frames as subviews.
I hope it helps you.